# Space adjacent children equally using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a requirement for spacing a set of `li` elements equaly. The caveat is that some of the elements can be hidden via a *CSS* class.

```
<ul class="list-spacing">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

The *CSS* I have is as follows:

```
.list-spacing > li + li {
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

The output looks good. See fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/njphghpa/

Now as I mentioned some `li` can be hidden via a class as follows:

```
<ul class="list-spacing">
  <li class='hidden'>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li class='hidden'>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

Now we get an unnecessary top margin of 10px for the second `li` (containing Two).
See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mL11uogw/

So I did this:

```
.list-spacing > li:first-child.hidden + li {
  margin-top:0;
}
```

See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/zuLhome9/
Again looks good.

But the problem is when the first two or three `li` are hidden, the above does not work. - https://jsfiddle.net/arryv6go/

I tried a different approach - setting the top margin of the `ul` to `-10px` and top margin of all children to `10px` and this happens: https://jsfiddle.net/yzbnvmez/, which is OK as long as the `ul` does NOT have a border. But I want one.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simplest solution that I can think of:

You need to add `margin-top:10px` to **every** li element, and then remove the gap on top of the list by setting `::before` pseudo-element margin-top to -10px

```
.list-spacing::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
.list-spacing > li {
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/JacobDesight/njphghpa/3/

Comment: Nice! This way, no need for a parent element. +1

Comment: Excellent. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flexbox to fix this.

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.list-spacing{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-spacing">
  <li class='hidden'>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li class='hidden'>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Gerard, but I want a spacing of 10px.

Comment: This won't work as long as there is no set height on the ul element.

Answer (score 1):

The **simplest and most robust way** to achieve your aim is to use the technique you mentioned at the end of your answer using a negative top margin on the `ul` element. Negative margins are perfectly valid btw, [see w3.org margin properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties).
Although it requires to add a parent element to prevent previous and next siblings overlapping and give a border around all the elements. Here is an example with your markup :

```css
.wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.list-spacing {
  margin: -10px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.list-spacing>li {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border:1px solid green;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <ul class="list-spacing">
    <li class='hidden'>One</li>
    <li class='hidden'>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li class='hidden'>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is definitely an option. Was just wondering if there's any css hack to make this work without another element.

Comment: If your `ul` has a fixed height, you can go for the flexbox solution, otherwise nothing I can suggest other than this solution.

Answer (score 0):

This selector should do what you need:

```
.list-spacing > li:not(.hidden) + li,  
.list-spacing > li:not(:first-of-type) + li{
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pbzg39wg/1/

Comment: Nice one! but if there are two hidden elements in a row, it won't work : https://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/pbzg39wg/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
.list-spacing > li:not(.hidden) {
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

use the `:not()` selector that excludes all elements with `.hidden` class.

Answer (score 0):

KISS: Keep It Simple, Stupid is my work mantra. How about replacing `margin-top`with `margin-bottom`? That should solve your problems.

To keep everything with 0 margins, then a negative margin on your `ul` is the best option as web-tiki suggests.

```
ul{ margin-bottom: -10px; margin-top: 0; }
li{ margin-bottom: 10px; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3fsofxa8/

Comment: Your mantra is my mantra too! But then I get an extra gap at the bottom of the UL. I want the last LI to touch the bottom border.

Comment: Thanks - but I still lose the bottom border - https://jsfiddle.net/3fsofxa8/2/ This is similar to the negative top margin I have suggested in my question